# SimpleITK - How to increment/decrement the value of every Pixel in an Image efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, itk

I wanted to know if there is an efficient way of incrementing or decrementing the value of every pixel in an ITK-Image-Object by 1.

```
def increment_image(image,value):
imageSize = image.GetSize()
for z in range(imageSize[2]):
    for y in range(imageSize[1]):
        for x in range(imageSize[0]):
            if (image.GetPixel(x,y,z) + value) >  255:
                image.SetPixel(x,y,z,255)
            else:
                image.SetPixel(x,y,z,image.GetPixel(x,y,z)+value)
```

This is the way i made it up, basically it's just looping trough every pixel of my 3D Image and adds 1 to the value....

This works but is highly inefficient, an 512x512x25 sized image takes about 10 minutes on my machine and it should work with images sizes way bigger than that, soo maybe you guys have ideas :)

Thanks for your help :)

PS: No third party libraries out of SITK / NumPy please :)

Comment: Googling yields some results that indicate that `Get/SetPixel` is very slow, and suggests that you should use an iterator instead to address every pixel in turn. See [Here](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/ImageIteratorsPage.html) and [Here](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageIterator.html). Some of the iterators have write access, so you should be able to accomlish your task quite simply.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I can't find any Iteration related stuff in SimpleITK ( Sorry, could only add an ITK Tag when asking the question)

Comment: Have you looked at the `AddImageFilter` class? It accepts two inputs, one of which can be a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overloaded image operators to achieve this. Something like (casting may be needed):

```
image += (image<255)*value
```

You need to think about operating on the whole image at once, not on each pixel one by one.

p.s. Unfortunately the SimpleITK pixel iterators are still slow.